# Trying to open minecraft in ubuntu

Tags: minecraft

I'm wondering something. Whenever i right click on minecraft and click open with another application, i try to find Java JDK. I have installed it for minecraft itself, but i just cant find where java is on the list of other applications. Any help?

Comment: Try /usr/bin/java, or, in a terminal window, `which java`.

Comment: mikewhatever, i have used that custom command, but it for some reason doesnt even load anything. Any help? I am also using Java JDK 7 Runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I wrote [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/613998/367165):

For some reason the desktop file for OpenJDK is not installed, even though this file is listed.

```
$ apt-file list openjdk-8-jre | grep desktop        
openjdk-8-jre: /usr/share/applications/openjdk-8-java.desktop
openjdk-8-jre: /usr/share/applications/openjdk-8-policytool.desktop

$ ls -l /usr/share/applications/openjdk-8-java.desktop
ls: cannot access /usr/share/applications/openjdk-8-java.desktop: No such file or directory

$ dpkg --get-selections | grep openjdk-8
openjdk-8-jre:amd64             install
```

Install Java with these commands, in order to get the required entry:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

---

And in order to do things more easily, use the *Minecraft Installer*.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:minecraft-installer-peeps/minecraft-installer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install minecraft-installer
```

Then run Minecraft from the Dash.

Comment: @poccy2010 Were you satisfied with my answer? Then give me a upvote (∧). If I could solve your problem, then it would be nice if you'd mark my answer (✓). http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers ;)