# how to get openJDK7 and Technic launcher to work on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: java, launcher, minecraft

I just installed Ubuntu 15.04 on my daughters computer. Now we cant get Technic launcher to work for her. Then she wants to play minecraft modes. I download the Tech jar file and marked it as open as program but it dosnt work. If i right click and to change Open with... I cant find OpenJDK anywhere. What is wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to open minecraft in ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/613798/trying-to-open-minecraft-in-ubuntu)

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/a/613998/367165

Answer (score 0):

Simply navigate to the folder in terminal, i.e `~/Downloads/`
and type into terminal:

```
java -jar TechnicLauncher.jar
```