# how can i convert a .jar to ubuntu-freindly code?

Tags: java, minecraft, convert

i am trying to figure out how to convert a .jar minecraft file into Ubuntu-friendly. the problem is, that Ubuntu does not recognize java.

Comment: If java is not installed, you can see this related post:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/613798/trying-to-open-minecraft-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

First, add the Java repository:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
```

Then, install the Java runtime:

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Once that's done, make sure that Minecraft has the permissions to launch:

```
chmod +x Minecraft.jar
```

Then, launch Minecraft like so:

```
java -jar Minecraft.jar
```

From this point on, you should also just be able to double-click on the Jarfile.

<sup>[(src)](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-on-ubuntu-with-apt-get)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You hava to install Java JDK or Java JRE. If you don't want to develop something in java then you can install java to run this game. You can try any of these two method.

You can go to ubuntu software centre and search for java. Install "**OpenJDK Java 7 Runtime**".

You can use terminal to install OpenJDK

> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre

[image]

After JRE installation right click on the minecraft.jar file and go to **Properties**.  Go to **Permission** and then select as "Allow executing file as program". Then go to **Open With** tab and select **OpenJDK Java 7 Runtime** and click on **Set as default**.

[image]

Now you are good to go. **Just double click on minecraft.jar file**.

Comment: thank you all for the answers! I'm really amazed what you can do to make java work on Ubuntu! At first I have thought that playing minecraft on Ubuntu is IMPOSSIBLE. but now I know it will work :D